# Exporting Selected By Attribute To Shapefile In ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

we can do a selection by "select by Attribute" and using RtClick on `layer --> Data-->Export Data-->Export Selected Features` output the selected as `.shp` format file. Now I am trying to do this in ModelBuilder (Using the NEW_SELECTION type of selection) like :

[image]

But I couldn't figure it out what tool I should use to export ONLY the selected part in ModelBuilder.

Can you please let me know what should I use here?

Comment: You can just use a single tool called Select (Analysis) to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As PolyGeo indicated in the comments, [Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000005000000) will do this in one step. Otherwise, use [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) to copy the selected features.

> Copies features from the input feature class or layer to a new feature
>   class. If the input is a layer which has a selection, only the
>   selected features will be copied. If the input is a geodatabase
>   feature class or shapefile, all features will be copied.

In this example, it is assumed you dragged the feature layer from the table of contents into your model--otherwise, you will need to incorporate the [Make Feature Layer (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a SQL select the above is fine. If you want to do a Spatial select, for example give me all the roads that intersect with this county polygon (i.e. I'm not wanting to clip the data), then the basic recipe for this not uncommon task:

Data Mgmt Tools > Layers and Table Views > Make Feature Layer Tool (e.g County)

Data Mgmt Tools > Layers and Table Views > Make Feature Layer Tool (e.g Roads)

link those 2 outputs with this next one

Data Mgmt Tools > Layers and Table Views > Select Layer By Location Tool

link selection output to this one

Data Mgmt Tools > Features > Copy Features (e.g. Cnty_Rds)

Reading this back, I missed where Aaron said to use Copy Features. I thought he was saying Copy_management. Anyway..